# Trying to make my objects within my object use their ids for my useState

Tags: arrays, reactjs, object, use-state

I'm making a decision tree and my `const responses` used to be an array, but if I ever need to delete or add an object my `jumpToQuestion` would mess up all the responses and become misaligned. SO, I figured I could make my array an object with objects in it and some arrays and the responses could be linked by ids instead of array placement to jump to. I've just assigned ids to all my responses. I just do know if I'm configuring it right.

PS Not all my responses are here, just so there isnt so much code.

```
 const responses = {
      id: 1,
      questionText: "Is the account data entry?",
      answerOptions: [
        { answerText: "No", isCorrect: false },
        { answerText: "Yes", isCorrect: true, jumpToQuestion: 6 },
      ],
      notes: [
      ],
    
      id: 2,
      questionText: "Is this customer 1 or 2?",
      answerOptions: [
        { answerText: "No", isCorrect: false },
        { answerText: "Yes", isCorrect: true, jumpToQuestion: 7 },
      ],
      notes: [
      ],
      id: 3,
      questionText: "Is the caller",
      answerOptions: [
        { answerText: "Power of Attorney/Conservator", isCorrect: true, jumpToQuestion: 15 },
        { answerText: "Lawyer", isCorrect: true, jumpToQuestion: 13 },
        { answerText: "Emergency Responder", isCorrect: true, jumpToQuestion: 14 },
        { answerText: "Wanting to make a payment", isCorrect: true, jumpToQuestion: 14 },
        { answerText: "None", isCorrect: false },
      ],
      notes: [
      ],
    }
  

  

  const [currentQuestion, setCurrentQuestion] = useState(1);

  const handleAnswerButton = (jumpToQuestion) => {
    const nextQuestion = jumpToQuestion || currentQuestion + 1;
    setCurrentQuestion(nextQuestion);
  }


  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="appWrapper">
        <div className="headerContainer">
          <div className="alderlogo">
            <img src={Logo} alt="Logo" />
          </div>
          <div class="vl"></div>
          <h1 className="headerName">Verification Procedure</h1>
          
        </div>

        <button className="backBtn"><i class="fas fa-arrow-left fa-2x"></i></button>

        <h2>{responses[currentQuestion].questionText}</h2>
        <div className="answerSection">
          {responses[currentQuestion].answerOptions.map((answerOption) => (
            <button onClick={() => { handleAnswerButton(answerOption.jumpToQuestion) }}>{answerOption.answerText}</button>
            ))}
        </div>
        <div class="hl"></div>
        <div className="notesContainer">
          {responses[currentQuestion].notes.map((notePoints) => (
            <li>{notePoints.note}</li>
            ))}
          <h3>{responses[currentQuestion].addnotes}</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with your assessment that you should use id vs the index of an array to find a question. However I would create and array of objects and the id should be a simple slug. You can use [slugify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/slugify) to help.

My response object:

```
const responses = [
  {
      id: question_1,
      questionText: "Is the account data entry?",
      answerOptions: [
        { answerText: "No", isCorrect: false },
        { answerText: "Yes", isCorrect: true, jumpToQuestion: question_6 },
      ],
      notes: [
      ],
  },
  {
      id: question_2,
      questionText: "Is this customer 1 or 2?",
      answerOptions: [
        { answerText: "No", isCorrect: false },
        { answerText: "Yes", isCorrect: true, jumpToQuestion: question_7 },
      ],
      notes: [
      ]
  },
  {
      id: question_3,
      questionText: "Is the caller",
      answerOptions: [
        { answerText: "Power of Attorney/Conservator", isCorrect: true, jumpToQuestion: question_15 },
        { answerText: "Lawyer", isCorrect: true, jumpToQuestion: question_13 },
        { answerText: "Emergency Responder", isCorrect: true, jumpToQuestion: question_14 },
        { answerText: "Wanting to make a payment", isCorrect: true, jumpToQuestion: question_14 },
        { answerText: "None", isCorrect: false },
      ],
      notes: [
      ],
  }
```

This **id** could then be used in your html and should provide an easy way to anchor link to the questions. I wouldn't recommend an arbitrary integer for your **ids** since you want to make sure they won't conflict with any other potential elements.

You could also then use [Lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#find) find method in your code if you need an easy way to return a specific response:

```
_.find(responses, ['id','question_1'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Everything sounds ok by me.
It is to the best of my knowledge that using IDs to identify a particular item, for example a user is a good practice.

However, I would consider doing ARRAY of OBJECTS, that way you can iterate easily, and adjust as needed, I think ?

Check it out: [CODE SANDBOX](https://codesandbox.io/s/blissful-agnesi-e74hw?file=/src/App.js)

I tried to see how it works, the questions start from 1, if answer wrong, the next one shows, if press yes, it sets the question to 6 etc etc.